# Sum JavaScript multidimensional array recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to sum the total of a multi dimensional array in JavaScript however it doesn't provide the right value because the nested array concatenates with the sum. Below is my code:

```
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 3], [10, 50], 98, 100];

    function recursion(array, length = 0) {
        if (array.length === length) return 0;

        if (Array.isArray(array[length])) {
            recursion(array[length]);
        }
        console.log(array[length]);

        return array[length] + recursion(array, length + 1);
    }

    console.log(recursion(arr));
```

The error can be seen in the below screenshot which is the console of google chrome.
[image]

Comment: Well, the first problem you have is that JavaScript doesn't support default function arguments. (At least not in the manner you have in your code.) See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: If recursion is not required, you could accomplish this much more simply using `concat` and `reduce`: `[].concat(...arr).reduce((a, b) => a + b)`

Comment: @StephenThomas Note, `javascript` does support default parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a function for this. The capability is built into `Array` prototypes.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 3], [10, 50], 98, 100]
const sum = [].concat(...arr).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: That is a fantastic solution friend. could you please tell me what is the concept of three dots (...arr) there?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `return`:

```
...
if (Array.isArray(array[length])) {
    return recursion(array[length]);
}
...
```

P.S. I'd recommend changing the parameter name from `length` to something else (perhaps `position`) to avoid confusion with the `length` property of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sum(e) {                      // take an element and return it if it's not an array or return the recursive sum if it's an array
  if(e instanceof Array) {             // if it's an array
    return e.reduce(function(s, e) {   // call sum on each item of the array and return the accumulated sum
      return s + sum(e);
    }, 0);
  }
  else                                 // else (if it's not an array) then return the item
    return e;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 3], [10, 50], 98, 100];

console.log(sum(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use `reduce()`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 3],[10, 50], 98, 100];

function recursion(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(r, e) {
    return r += Array.isArray(e) ? recursion(e) : e
  }, 0)
}

console.log(recursion(arr));
console.log(recursion([1, [[[1, [[[2]]]]]]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not necessary. You can use `.toString()`, `.split()`, `.reduce()`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 3], [10, 50], 98, 100];
var n = arr.toString().split(/,/).reduce(function(a, b) {return +a + +b});

console.log(n);
```